# .htaccess working on one domain but not another same server

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an htaccess file that redirects ALL urls and subdomains to index.php.

It is working fine on one domain but not on another. The only difference is that one domain is a .ca and the other a .com.

They are both hosted on the same server. Here is my access file if anyone can tell me if there is something in this file that is causing the problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
RewriteEngine on
#this rule removes www from the URL if its used
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#this rule handles the subdomains
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php[L]

#this rule handles redirecting all addresses to index.php
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

It works on

http://admin.kaalaphp.com

http://admin.rtbstats.com

but not on

http://admin.sherwoodmarine.ca
UPDATE THIS DOMAIN WORKS NOW BECAUSE I ADDED THE SUBDOMAIN IN CPANEL

I did not need to add the subdomain on the other sites though the htaccess looked after it

Comment: Are you placing the file in the location / path? the file presence in one directory will not affect all directories, it has to be in the root directory

Comment: What is not working on `.ca` site? Are you sure you placed above rules in DOCUMENT_ROOT of new site?

Comment: the .htaccess file is the same on both sites as per the links in the question. It is in the root of the site.

Comment: You mean `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is pointing to same path for both sites?

Comment: DOCUMENT_ROOT is different on each site. The .htaccess is in the document root of each site.

Comment: You have a missing space here: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php[L]` before `[L]`. Also can you provide `VirtualHost` entries of both sites.

Comment: Also `http://admin.sherwoodmarine.ca/` is loading some default test page which could be due to its DOCUMENT_ROOT pointing somewhere else.

Comment: I have added the space RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L] did not fix the problem. I will try and get the VirtualHost entries

Comment: I have this system running on 3 domains and the only one with a problem is the .ca domain. The other two are working fine. They are all hosted on the same dedicated server.

Comment: I understand that and that's why I suspect that may be `DOCUMENT_ROOT` for `.ca` is pointing somewhere else and you are putting your files somewhere else.

Comment: Document root is pointing to the correct folder I dumped out the $_SERVER variables and checked.

Comment: Just checked the phpinfo() on both domains and the settings are all the same (save the $_SERVER settings which are for each domain).

Comment: I think it is something in this line that is causing the problem.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.(.*)$ [NC]

for some

Answer (score 1):

Virtual host definition for that domain might not allow to override settings via .htaccess.
Show us virtual host settings from Apache configuration.

Comment: The settings on the server are the same for both domains. They are hosted on the same dedicated server.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the tutorial here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles

(This is not Ubuntu related, but specific to Apache).

The htaccess file is considered if the AllowOverride directive is set.

Comment: The htaccess is working on http://admin.kaalaphp.com but the same htaccess file does not redirect correctly on http://admin.sherwoodmarine.ca. The server settings for both domains in the same. I have installed this CMS system on other .com domains with no problem. It just seems to not work on the .ca domain which leads me to believe it might be something with the htaccess file.

Comment: How can they be something wrong when it works as you mentioned? Did you really read that post? Did you look at the AllowOverride directive, and can you confirm that it is set to 'All' for the directory?